# Splitting a large PHP class

Tags: php, class, oop, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

I have a large class (1500 lines, but will soon be several times that) that I'd like to split so that it fits better with [SRP](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) (and so that each file is smaller and more manageable.)

The class contains 50-100 properties, and has several different types of actions that are performed against it - one of which would be an `update` which in turn does several steps such as update the database, and send emails.

So I think I want 4 classes.

How should I structure the classes?

---

Here's a simplified version of what I have now:

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct ($params) {}

    public function update () {
        $this->updateDatabase();
        $this->sendEmails();
    }

    private function updateDatabase () {}
    private function sendEmails () {}
}

$foo = new Foo($params);
$foo->update();
```

`updateDatabase()` and `sendEmails ()` each call many other methods - hundreds of lines of code each, and they have several sibling methods doing other tasks.

A basic rewrite to use static methods

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct ($params) {}
}

class FooUpdate {
    public static function update ($fooParam) {
        FooUpdateDatabase::main($fooParam);
        FooSendEmails::main($fooParam);
    }
}

class FooUpdateDatabase {
    public static function main ($fooParam) {}
}

class FooSendEmails {
    public static function main ($fooParam) {}
}

$foo = new Foo($params);
FooUpdate::update($foo);
```

A basic rewrite to use instantiated objects

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct () {}
}

class FooUpdate {
    private $foo;
    public function __construct ($fooParam) {
        $this->foo = $fooParam;
    }
    public function main () {
        $fooTemp = FooUpdateDatabase($this->fooParam);
        $fooTemp->main();
        $fooTemp = FooSendEmails($this->fooParam);
        $fooTemp->main();
    }
}

class FooUpdateDatabase {
    private $foo;
    public function __construct ($fooParam) {
        $this->foo = $fooParam;
    }
    public function main () {}
}

class FooSendEmails {
    private $foo;
    public function __construct ($fooParam) {
        $this->foo = $fooParam;
    }
    public function main () {}
}

$foo = new Foo($bar, ...);
$fooTemp = new FooUpdate($foo);
$fooTemp->update();
```

Or should I use inheritance or traits somehow?

Comment: You would get the most (appropriate) feedback at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) I'm thinking.

Comment: @Marcus Please note that Foo/Bar identifiers would make it an inappropriate Code Review question.

Comment: @200_success Good point. With that said, I see this question as being highly opinion-based.

Comment: @Redzarf - I would advise against creating such restrictive classes such as `FooSendEmails{}`, or even `FooUpdateDatabase{}` Consider creating an `Email` class which can *house* the various methods to perform your varying actions. This would be a good opportunity for you to implement polymorphism  using a Factory class to determine, say, what kind of email to send (E.g. HTML, plain-text, attachments, etc), then create the additional *email type* classes which implement a common interface. And what about `FooInsertDatabase`? `FooSelectDatabase`? Create separate classes to perform those actions?

Comment: @Marcus - yes, I have separate classes that handle the sending of emails and database actions. So `FooSendEmails()` does things like build display versions of data to be inserted into the email template, and work out who the email should be sent to - actions that are unique to `Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

As @SparK says,

- Your object (Foo)
- A class that handles database communication (FooRepository)
- A class that sends mails (Mailer)
- A class that wraps it all (FooManager)

  ```
  $foo = new Foo($params);
  $fooManager = new FooManager(FooRepository, Mailer);
  $fooManager->update($foo);
  $fooManager->notify($foo); //this could be inside the update or an event.
  ```

This way you can also decompose your classes (ie: separate a class that handles database connections and inject it in the FooRepository, etc). But I don't think having classes that represent an action is the way to go?

Classes are objects that can do actions (among other things), not actions (this is just a comment because of the names you used in your example :p).

Comment: Thanks, I think the Manager class is the concept I need to read more about. Can you explain your second line of code? Or is it shorthand for `$fooRepository = new FooRepository(); $mailer = new Mailer(); $fooManager = new FooManager($fooRepository, $mailer);`

Comment: Is there any reason to create an instance of `FooManager` instead of it just having static methods (seeing as `$foo` is going to be passed in as a param anyway).

Comment: @Redzarf Yes just a shorthand. But you could also pass interfaces instead of those classes (ie: MailerInterface) in the constructor definition of FooManager. When creating it you will then need to pass a Mailer object that implements that interface. That is useful if your app is growing and other people is going to work on it.
--- If FooManager has static methods how will you pass the FooRepository and the Mailer. You can create them in the static functions but I don't see a reason for that to be, maybe I'm wrong. Also, if another object needs to use a FooManager, you can just inject it.

Comment: @Blitu, you could call the `FooManager` a façade then. I guess it wouldn't have the notify method, as it would coordinate the notification inside the manager (update method, et.al.) code (if mailer is not null).

Comment: @SparK Yes, and also implement it as a Singleton. Most important thing is to reduce complexity and let each element be concerned about its role and not others.

Answer (score 2):

I guess sending e-mails is one thing, representing your data is another and read-write operations to database would be a third.

So `class Foo`, `class FooPersistence`, `class FooMailer`.
And whoever **calls** the `FooPersistence::update($foo)` should also call `FooMailer::sendUpdateNotification($foo)`.

As a side note:
If you had something like Events set up I would trigger the "update event" inside the persistence class and add a listener to it which sends e-mails.

Comment: @Redzarf I'll just leave it here as a comment because it's not really part of the answer nor the main topic of the question but a complement of the side note: https://github.com/SparK-Cruz/elpho/blob/master/samples/events/Events.php